# Order WooCommerce orders per user role - conflict

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add filtering roles to the order page. I have used something like this

http://jeroensormani.com/order-woocommerce-orders-per-user-role/

and it works perfectly but .. my custom dropdown in orders page with shows the delivery date of the product (pastebin url), stops working after I added this orders per user role feature.

https://pastebin.com/9mPBGFUj

I will be very very grateful for your help in resolving this issue.

Woocommerce version: 2.6.14

Comment: When this issue has started… (after WooCommerce update?)… Please add more details (updating your question) as your question is unclear and nobody can help you actually.

Comment: My custom dropdown in orders page with shows the delivery date of the product (pastebin url), stops working after I added a orders per user role function (jeroensormani URL).

Comment: which version of woocommerce are you using? please update your question… add more details to it (Not in comments… update your question)… do you get any errors?